# iPhone 6s unresponsive display when unlocked

Tags: ios, iphone

My iPhone 6s was updated to iOS 11.0.2 recently. After that I began experiencing various unresponsiveness problems. Today it got even worse; my phone's display is 100% unresponsive **when unlocked**. *However, when locked the display works as normal.* So I can use the camera, browse the lock-screen widgets, and use Siri. This means I can make calls to people in my phone book. But if somebody calls the phone, it rings but there's no option to answer the call.

I cannot reboot the phone as the power on/off button on the side won't show the slider to turn off the phone. However, that same button works to lock the phone.

This doesn't appear to be a hardware problem as everything works (save for the power off function) when the phone is locked.

I tried to reset the phone in iTunes, but it wouldn't let me because "Find my friends" must be disabled first, which I obviously cannot do.

What are my options here? I'd like to resolve this quickly as I'm traveling abroad today and need my phone. I can think of only two things:

1. Make the battery run out and hope that something changes when I power the device up again. I can drain the battery faster if I light up the flashlight
2. Enter a wrong passcode over and over until the phone resets itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It occurred after iphone music app became stuk while loading. Phone wouldn't turn off and wouldn't respond to swipe or changeing the app. 
I pressed down simultaneously on the home button and the off button on the side . After awhile the phone shut down and the slider bar appeared and I was able to shut the phone off. Than able to turn it on and things are working now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you're a savior! Pressing all of the buttons at the same time does turn off the phone. Much better than draining the battery with the flashlight :-)